# play order in the iPhone Music app

Tags: iphone, music.app

iPhone 4 running iOS 6.0.1.

I have Settings -> Music -> Shake to Shuffle turned off.

Without tapping the shuffle icon, if I select the first track on an album or a playlist, Music *will not* run through those tracks in start-to-finish order. It's always randomized in some way.

Needless to say, this makes listening to a "live" album fairly distracting...

Google has been no help, and other questions here get as far as "close, but not quite."

Am I missing a setting, somewhere?

Comment: So the shuffle icon is *not* orange? Maybe you could post a screen shot? Can you play any album with the tracks ordered correctly?

Comment: The shuffle icon is grey/blue. So far, no album/playlist has played in order.